# How to send body to post request

Tags: python, python-requests

I am using an api which takes html code as input.Lets say it is accesible at http://10.21.2.80:8000/Application/validate_content.php

## validate_content.php

```
$html_data =  trim(urldecode($_POST['html'])); // html is key
validate($html_data)
```

## access.py

I am sending a request to this api using python requests like

```
import requests 
openfile = open('file.txt')  
html_data = openfile.read()
openfile.close()
url = http://10.21.2.80:8000/Application/validate_content.php?id=12&offset=10
response = requests.post(url,data={'html':html_data})
```

validate() checks weather html code follows 508 compliance rules or not. If it follows the rules then it returns PASS, else it returns the errors in the code.
When I am making request using POSTMAN, the API is giving right response(Validating and returning errors). But with python code it is always returning PASS.
I don't know what went wrong. Can anyone suggest me the right way to do it.

Comment: What do you mean that it is not the right response? What do you expect and what are you actually getting?

Comment: What is the correct response? What does `validate()` do? Does it write any output? The Python code looks OK (although it is sending URL parameters in the query string that are apparently not used). How about debugging your PHP code? Are you emitting the correct headers in PHP?

Comment: validate() checks weather HTML follows 508 compliance rules or not. 
I tried this using postman. Which is working fine. So I think there is  nothing wrong with php code.

Comment: @AKS I have added the response.

Comment: Does `validate()` output the required HTTP headers before writing the results of its compliance check? Or are the headers being sent elsewhere in code that you haven't shown?

Comment: Can you check if `html_data` in the php file is what you want it to be?

Comment: Headers are being sent separately.

Comment: It is getting the proper html_data.